# The settings in the settings manager have no affect

Tags: unity

The problem is that when I try to change the options from the System Settings from the panel tray it does not change. I removed unity and installed it again but the same problem continues, even after trying `unity --reset` still the problem persists. Even the icon settings are not persistent, I mean when I close and open they get back to the default (I mean close and again not restarting).

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I think I had the same problem, and here’s how I fixed it.

In `/etc/dconf/profile`, there were two small text files, “gdm” and “user”. “gdm” looked like this:

```
user-db:user
system-db:gdm
```

whereas “user” looked like this:

```
user
gdm
```

So, I changed “user” to look exactly like “gdm” (`sudo nano /etc/dconf/profile/user` will work), restarted, and suddenly, all the settings worked again. So, check to see if you have the files “gdm” and “user”, and see if they look like what I had before. If so, try doing what I did and see if that works. Good luck!